# SQL - test if numeric field is holding an integer

Tags: sql, divide

I have numbers (from my select)

```
    col1         col2
  1. 3.6   and    3
  2. 3.6   and    5
```

I want this

```
if(col1/col2 = integer)
    update column
else(col1/col2  = decimal number)
    update column
```

Any idea how to get is number integer or decimal?

Comment: if your col1 is always float/decimal/real and then you divide it with int output will never be an INT unless you CAST

Comment: you could use this to check, if the decimal value is close enough to an integer: `case when a.col1/a.col2 = round(a.col1/a.col2, 0) then 'integer' else 'decimal' end` - at least in MySQL

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Some products behave differently here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use modulo 1 (% 1), and if the remainder is zero then you have your 'integer'. For example, with SQL Server:

```
if (col1 / col2 ) % 1 = 0 
   -- integer
else
   -- decimal
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it